# Reporting the quanity of each product in Odoo inventory

Tags: report, odoo-9, inventory-management

I searched for a solution to have a report in Odoo 9.0 showing the on-hand quantity changes of each product in my warehouse locations for example in the last 3 months. But nothing I found.
Any help please?

Comment: Have you seen any tutorials on youtube?

Comment: I searched the whole forum of odoo website but I didn't chance to have a look at youtube. Do you have any good video which I can directly to it? or you kindly suggest to watch generally?

Comment: See this - http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=LfaN3kbF32s Let me know if it  helped you.

Comment: Dear AT-2016, It was helpful and gave me some very good points but it was not what I was looking for. What I need is a report in which it has something like a graph that says what happened to the quantity of a product during a period of time. Am I clear or need more explanation?